# Form not getting submitted if we press enter by changing check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a form with some textboxes and checkbox.

If I change something in the textbox and I click enter the form is getting submitted and If I change the checkbox and click enter then the form is not getting submitted.

```
this.content.find('.form').on('keypress', function (self) {
    alert(window.event.keyCode);
    if(self.keyCode==13) {
         alert("Boom Boom");
    }
});
```

But this is not working

Comment: post a fiddle please

Comment: @HimanshuTanwar what does fiddle mean ?

Comment: add your html, css and js here https://jsfiddle.net/  and provide the shared url

Comment: Firstly, your code is invalid and doesn't make sense regarding `this.keyCode==13`, it should be regarding your code `self.keyCode==13` and you should use `which` not `keyCode`. But that said, it has nothing to do with your question/issue, so?! Now try replicate your issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/3ohfeygL/

Comment: Thats company code. i cant paste that there. and it is a combination of so many layers

Comment: @VenkatesswaraRaoDevarapalem So something else avoid form to get submited...

Comment: Whithout your html makes hard to help you.

Comment: you can use the spacebar to toggle checkbox inputs without submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Use your "self" event, like this:

```js
$('.form').on('keypress', function (self) {
  if(self.keyCode==13) {
    alert("Boom Boom");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form"><input type="text"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('clicked');
        // $('form').submit();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type='text' /> <br/>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  
 <form>
```

Comment: @VenkatesswaraRaoDevarapalem could you please vote this answer ;)